# Create a Recursive Function as Well as a Closed Function Definition

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, math

The goal of this assignment is to take the recurrence relation given at the bottom, and then create a recursive function under `recFunc(n)`, as well as a closed function definition underneath `nonRecFunc(n)`. A closed function means our function should solely depend on n, and that its output should
match the recursive function's exactly. Then, find the value for n = 15 and n = 20, and use it as instructed below. You should probably need to use a characteristic equation to solve this problem.

What is the value for `nonRecFunc(20)` (divided by) `nonRecFunc(15)`, rounded to the nearest integer.

Problem:

> > > Solve the recurrence relation a_n = 12a_n-1 - 32a_n-2 with initial conditions a_0 = 1 and a_1 = 4.

I am confused as to how I should attack this problem and how I can use recursion to solve the issue.

```
def recFunc(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return 2
    else:
        return recFunc(n - 1) + 6 * recFunc(n - 2)


def nonRecFunc(n):
    return 4/5 * 3 ** n + 1/5 * (-2) ** n


for i in range(0,10):
    print(recFunc(i))
    print(nonRecFunc(i))
    print()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is - at a quick glance the posted source code seems to show you how to solve your problem; you just need to plug in the correct constants.

Comment: The problem says "Solve the recurrence relation a_n = 12a_n-1 - 32a_n-2 with initial conditions a_0 = 1 and a_1 = 4." How would I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Asking to be spoon-fed answers doesn't usually go down well here; you have enough information to solve the recursion part easily, but converting the recursive function to a closed one might be awkward, and help for that might be better on [math.se].

Comment: I am not asking for answers, I asked for a process. What is the method to conquering the problem, what methods can be used, and what applications would this have to recursion? I think the question I posed is quite intuitive. Maybe you misunderstood the question? Thanks for the help!

Comment: But you have shown concise recursive solution for coefficients 1,6 and starting values 1,2. What stops you from changing them to 12,32 and 1,4?

Comment: Well, assuming that you manage the really quite simple part of recursion, you could assume a similar functional behaviour as in the example. So you could generate points and try to fit the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a my comment above, I leave the recursive solution to you. 
For the more mathematical question of the non-recursive solution consider this:

you have

*x_n = a x_(n-1) + b x_(n-2)*

This means that the change of *x* is more or less proportional to *x* as *x_n* and *x_(n-1)* will be of same order of magnitude. In other words we are looking for a function type giving

d*f(n)*/d*n* ~ *f(n)*

This is something exponential. So the above assumption is

*x_n* = alpha t^n + beta s^n

(later when solving for *s* and *t* the motivation for this becomes clear) from the start values we get

*alpha + beta =* 1

and

*alpha t + beta s =* 2

The recursion provides

*alpha t^n + beta s^n = a ( alpa t^(n-1) + beta s^(n-1) ) + b ( alpa t^(n-2) + beta s^(n-2) )*

or

*t^2 alpha t^(n-2) + s^2 beta s^(n-2) = a ( t alpa t^(n-2) + s beta s^(n-2) ) + b ( alpa t^(n-2) + beta s^(n-2) )*

This equation holds for all *n* such that you can derive an equation for *t* and *s*.

Plugging in the results in the above equations gives you the non-recursive solution.

Try to reproduce it and then go for the actual task.

Cheers.